# Ceiling cracks on second level

Tags: ceiling, cracks

Any issues with these ceiling cracks on my second level. The blue room has new drywall. The green room doesn’t [[image: green room][1]]

Comment: Cold weather and dry air tends to create cracks. As long as you're not seeing foundation cracks, uneven floors, sagging roof, bowed walls, or any structural issue then that's likely just a vanity symptom.

Comment: The cure for this is back blocking, but you need to do that when the ceiling goes in.